# Python for loop accessing GPIO pins

Tags: python, for-loop, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

I'm new to Python and the Raspberry Pi. I'm trying to shorten my code and use `for` loops for repetitive parts in my code, like changing all pins to high and low.

I'm trying to use a `for` loop to access pins. Is this even possible?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

R1=22
R2=10
R3=9
R4=11

GPIO.setup(R1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(R2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(R3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(R4, GPIO.OUT)

for x in range(1, 5):
    print "We're on time %d" % (x)
    GPIO.output(R + %d % (x), GPIO.HIGH)
    sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(R + %d % (x), GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(1)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

That sort of thing is possible, but often nicer to use a `list` or `dict`:

```
pins = [22, 10, 9, 11]

for pin in pins:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

for x in range(1, 5):
    GPIO.output(pins[x], GPIO.HIGH)
    sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(pins[x], GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: That sort of thing *isn't* possible. They're trying to create a variable name dynamically: `R + '1'`, etc.

Comment: @PeterWood They're just trying to access variables that already exist, which can be done using `eval`, `exec`, etc (but isn't very nice).

Comment: I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create variable *names* like that. You have to have the same variable name and change what it is pointing to:

```
pins = [R1, R2, R3, R4]

for pin in pins:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

for pin in pins:
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
    sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(1)
```